# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_delta'

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, pyspark-pandas

My code used to work. Why does my code not work anymore? I updated to the newer Databricks runtime 10.2 so I had to change some earlier code to use pandas on pyspark.

```
# Drop customer ID for AutoML
automlDF = churn_features_df.drop(key_id)

# Write out silver-level data to autoML Delta lake
automlDF.to_delta(mode='overwrite', path=automl_silver_tbl_path)
```

The error I am getting is `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_delta'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work as expected using `to_pandas_on_spark()`. My working code looks like this:

```
# Drop customer ID for AutoML
automlDF = churn_features_df.drop(key_id).to_pandas_on_spark()

# Write out silver-level data to autoML Delta lake
automlDF.to_delta(mode='overwrite', path=automl_silver_tbl_path)
```